# How to add icon to text input layout label?

Tags: android-textinputlayout

Can I add icon to android text input layout label?

I want to create a text input layout like design below:

[image]

And this is the text input layout that I've created:

[image]

And this is my xml code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/text_color_primary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_tertiary"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextHintWhite"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="نام و نام خانوادگی"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_secondary"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/background_cursor_tertiary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16cdp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
<style name="EditTextHintWhite">
    <item name="colorError">@color/text_color_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/text_color_tertiary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/text_color_tertiary</item>
</style>
```

What should I do to add icons to label? Is it possible?